# jQuery next, parent, closest

Tags: jquery, html, click, closest

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="item" id="id_1">
      <h2>header</h2>
      <div class="c_image">
        <img/>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Click event on images must trigger a click event on the related h2.
The html is automatically rendered.

JS:

```
$(".container .item .c_image img").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    //console.log($(this).parent("li.item"));
    $(this).closest("h2")[0].click();
  });
});
```

What is the best solution is this situation,
I tried closest but it doesn't trigger the h2 click event.

This works fine:

```
$('#id_1 .c_image img').click(function(){
  $('li#id_1 h2')[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`closest('h2')` won't work here as the `h2` is a sibling of a parent the `img` element. You would need to get the closest `li` and then `find()` the `h2`:

```
$(".container .item .c_image img").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find("h2").click();
});
```

Note that you don't need to iterate over the `img` elements and also that you could avoid the need for this code if you attach the event to the `li` instead of the `h2` as the event would then bubble up from both the `img` and the `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

`h2` element is previous sibling of clicked image parent. hence you can use `.parent()` along with `.prev()` selector

Also you don't need to iterate over elements individually to attach same event for them. you can simply bind the event to returned images object. Like this:

```
$(".container .item .c_image img").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().prev().click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

quote "Click event on images must trigger a click event on the related h2."
Assuming that the same event must happen whether the img or the heading is clicked.

could you not place the click event on the `li` rather

```
$(".container li").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var heading = $this.find('h2').html();
    console.log(heading);
});
```

cannot suggest better than what others have already without further understanding of why?